# Can the Browser Tab title not start with the tag name?

Tags: feature-request, title

Currently some of my browser tabs are titled like this:

[image: Tabs]

Since I guess most questions will start with an OS tag like [Windows] or [Linux] the title is partially useless and I can't see the rest which makes the complete title useless in my case.

Can the main tag be removed from the browser tab title?

Answer (score 3):

This is automatic, as I believe Chrome titles the tab based on the HTML `<title>` tag. The engine automatically sticks what it thinks is the most popular tag on a question *in* that title tag, even though it's not present on the actual title at the top of the question. This is part of the SEO strategy we employed to help climb over the SEO scrapers.

You still have the favicon, though I admit that they all start to look the same after a while if you're active on a few betas. But there's not much we can do about it, unfortunately.

Comment: If question titles contain a tag, then a tag is not automatically added to the web page title.